# Schengen visa denied by Slovenia despite being the main destination

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, slovenia

I'm an Indian and I'm planning a trip to Croatia (5 days), Slovenia (7 days) and Austria (2 days) in June. I applied for the visa at the Slovenian embassy given I'm spending the biggest number of days in their country.

However, they refused to grant the visa and indicated that I needed a Croatian visa first. Since Croatia allows travelers on a multiple-entry Schengen visa, is the Slovenian embassy right in doing this? Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Croatia allows holders of multiple-entry Schengen visas to enter without an additional visa. That does however obviously *not* mean that a consulate from an arbitrary Schengen state is obligated to issue you a Schengen visa with the purpose of visiting Croatia. You will likely only get a single-entry visa anyway for your stay in Slovenia and Austria and will need a separate visa from Croatia anyway.

Answer (score 1):

While the days in Slovenia were a few more than in Croatia, it may have been viewed as marginal, as a separate visa for Croatia would be required (and that Austria, 2 days, were for making flight connections).

[VFS Global in India visas for Slovenia](http://www.vfsglobal.com/slovenia/india/important_information.html) application launch page notes *Applicants travelling to Croatia for more number of days than Schengen must obtain Croatian Visa prior applying for Slovenian/Schengen visa.*

Whatever the reason(s) for the visa refusal, your only option is to comply, if that is what is necessary for the planned itinerary.

Comment: Where does Bosnia come into this?

Comment: ooops; corrected ty